# foreign table insertion is getting failed in concurrent transaction

Tags: redis

Redis foreign data wrapper in postgres is not responding correctly when concurrent transaction happened in production environment.
I am inserting foreign tables using rabbitmq and keeping a log table for each transaction.
But, every time I am getting key already exists(SQLSTATE-23505). In my db function in each transaction, I am checking whether key exists or not.
Multiple transactions are creating this issue. 
I am not facing the same issue in a single transaction and **development environment.**

Any os level change is required? 
Can anyone explain me the solution?

Comment: Log every redis command issued to server, you will see if there is a racing condition. Also it seems that the FDW doesn't support MULTI/EXEC.

Comment: Now i am trying to drop connection object when redis is failed to connect.So based on sqlstate i can check whether reconnection is required or not.But how to drop existing connection object and create default one.

Comment: Ask a new question about that.